# System.console() returning null in Command line during mvn test

Tags: java, maven

I am using `testng` as a unit test framework. Here is the snippet that depicts the issue.

```
public class Demo {
 Demo() {
  Console console = System.console();
  if (console == null) {
   System.err.println("Console not found");
  } else {
  console.writer().println("No issue with console");
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Demo();
 }
}
```

Test class

```
public class DemoTest {
 private Demo demo;
 @BeforeClass
 public void init() {
  demo = new Demo();
 }
}
```

When I run `mvn test`, of course ran it post clean and compilation phases but it says `Console not found` followed by `NullPointerException`

When I run the `Demo` class from CLI it works. Like when I say `java Demo` it prints
`No issue with console`

I am using `Java1.8`
& `Testng` version

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.14.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where's your `else`? your `if(console == null) {}` falls through to `console.writer().println()`, so do it in `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the javadocs from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the
>   underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual
>   machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an
>   interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and
>   output streams then its console will exist and will typically be
>   connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine
>   was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for
>   example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have
>   a console.

When you run your code via a `main()` method, then you are spinning off the JVM. But AFAIK, its not the same when you spin off the tests via maven or from within an IDE for that matter.

That explains why you see a null value.

Here's a related thread that adds more context : https://coderanch.com/t/641563/java/System-console-returns-null